# display variable with highest rank

Tags: javascript

How can i get the `var output` to display a `var one OR two OR three Or four`  depending on rank order (highest "one" lowest "four") and not including undefined. for eg

```
var one = //undefined
var two = "yes121";
var three = "no";
var four = "yes";
var output = // should be "yes121" as `var two` has the higest rank that is not undefined.
```

I had output as var output = one + two + three + four; but for obvious reasons that is unnecessary for what I am asking.

### Clarify

if i have four variables "one" "two" "three" and "four" how can i get the output variable to be set as the highest ranked variable which is "one" (and the lowest being "four") excluding lower ranked variables and higher ranked variables that are undefined.

Comment: Ummm... you don't.  Use a collection.  Using your variable names to define your program logic is horrible and leads to an unmaintainable mess of code.

Comment: just use array `var list = new Array();`

Comment: iv'e tried using if's but its really long and messy and doesn't work

Comment: And that is a strong indication that you are probably going about this the wrong way/trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Really long and messy and doesn't work?

Comment: What determines "highest rank" between two variables?  Why is "yes121" a higher rank than "yes" or "no"?  We can't help you solve this without understanding your algorithm for evaluating rank.

Comment: @jfriend00. I guess the 121 vs nothing.... ?!

Comment: no the actual variable ie "var one" or "var two" or "var three" etc

Comment: OP, you would essentially be making your code unchangeable by doing this as changing *a variable's name* would break it.  This is a really, *really* bad idea that many beginners stumble upon for whatever reason. Please read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: @Vega and gdoron, it sounds like you're guessing what they want.  I'd like to see Yusaf tell us what they want.

Comment: What are you trying to do, Yusaf? Why do you need to accomplish this? Related: Is this homework?

Comment: As it is, this question is unaswerable without wild guesses for what the question actual means.  I'm voting to close.  It could be a valid question if the OP clarifies it.

Comment: Any correct answer will (at this time) basically say that the OP is trying to solve an unknown problem in the wrong way. OP, give us a description of the problem you wish to solve, not your proposed solution that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have made it clearer what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: So want the value of the "highest-ranked" variable, not the variable name (as supposed in comments on my answer)?

Comment: @Bergi: Reading the "clarification" still tells me that the OP wants the variable name, not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand you correctly: you want to return the variable who's NAME is closest to zero ignoring variables whos VALUE is undefined?

The only way to do that is test them one by one for not being undefined:

```
var one = //undefined
var two = "yes121";
var three = "no";
var four = "yes";
var output;

if (one !=== undefined) output = one;
else if (two !=== undefined) output = two;
else if (three !=== undefined) output = three;
else if (four !=== undefined) output = four;
```

Alternatvely you could do this:

```
var output = one || two || three || four;
```

This can cause problems with falsy expressions though. (like '', 0, -1, NaN, etc)

However: I think what's you should do it create an array, so you can loop through it:

Answer (score 0):

Use the `||` operator. It will return the leftmost non-falsy value, e.g the expression

```
var output = one || two || three || four;
```

will return `"yes121"`. But non-falsy means an empty string will also be false; to check for `undefined` you really will have to loop through an array of values:

```
var vals = [undefined, "yes121", "no", "yes"];
var output = vals.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return (typeof a == "undefined") ? b : a;
});
```

Comment: OP wants to return the variable name, not the value.

Comment: @EdS.: No. How could you know a variable's name?

Comment: I agree, Bergi, but EdS does seem to be correct. I'm not sure the OP knows what they are doing.

Comment: @Bergi: exactly.  The question itself is asking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist/doesn't make sense.  We have a beginner asking for a solution to what *they perceive* to be the problem at hand.  In reality there are much better ways to solve whatever problem this is.  I see beginners doing this all the time; mapping program logic to a variable's name. Usually they just don't understand how to use collection types yet.

Comment: @gdoron: Why? In OPs configuration with `var one, two="yes121", three="no", four="yes";` it will return the value of `two`.

Comment: @Bergi: Read more closely.  He wants to return "two", i.e., the *name* of the variable itself in code, not its *value*.

Comment: And it was  `var one, two="dhfjdshfjdsnfdsjn", three="no", four="yes";` **?!**